# Iterate form fields in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a list of products and my product items have some specifications that are different depending on what type of product has been selected. So instead of making 3 different edit forms (1 for each product) I want to iterate over each form field in the list of my specifications.

However I can't use v-model on an iteration so I have to bind it to the `:value`, however I can't bind these values back dynamically to my form object.

How can I make my form dynamic by iterating over an object and binding it back to my form payload?

**v-for**

```
 <div v-for="(spec, index) in item.specs" :key="index">
    {{spec}}
    <v-text-field :name="spec" :label="index" :value="spec"></v-text-field>
 </div>
```

**Object**

I fill this object from my API return `this.specs = response.data.specs`

```
specs:{}
```

Comment: have you tried `v-model="item.spect[index]"` ?

Comment: thanks.....<v-text-field :name="spec" :label="index" :value="spec" v-model="item.specs[index]"></v-text-field>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  `v-model` for two-way data bindings. As

```
<div v-for="(spec, index) in item.specs" :key="index">
    {{spec}}
    <v-text-field :name="spec" :label="index" :value="spec" v-model='item.specs[index]'></v-text-field>
 </div>
```

Comment: I get an error....you are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias. This will not be able to modify the v-for source array because writing to the alias is like modifying a function local variable. Consider using an array of objects and use v-model on an object property instead.